# Wait for a thread before continue on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've one thread, but i'd like to wait for it to finish before continue with the next actions. How could i do it?

```
            new Thread(

                    new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mensaje = getFilesFromUrl(value);
                        }

                    }).start();
```

here i'd like to put something (but loops) that knows when thread finishes and evaluate the result (*mensaje*)

```
            btnOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblEstado.setText(mensaje);

            if(mensaje.equals("Importado"))
                startActivity(new Intent(ScanUrl.this, MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: use an AsyncTask and onPostExcute, or use a delegate to notify the thread excutation is ended

Comment: or add a callback listener for when the thread finishes

Answer (score 69):

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mensaje = getFilesFromUrl(value);
                        }});

t.start(); // spawn thread

t.join();  // wait for thread to finish
```

Comment: Need to put the t.join() in a try scope, as below: `try { t.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`